# Add missing months with values from previous month

Tags: sql

I need to use this SQL query for a software and get the time in a particular format hence the reason for the Time column however I need the query to insert the months that are missing with the value from the previous month. This is the query I currently have.

```
SELECT [accountnumber],SUM([postingamount]) AS Amount, [accountingdate],
convert(varchar(4),year(accountingdate))+'M'+ Format(DATEPART( MONTH, accountingdate)  , '00')
 AS [Time]
  FROM [7 GL Detail MACL]
  where [accountingdate]>='2019-01-01' 
  GROUP BY [accountingdate],[postingamount],[accountnumber]
```

[Current Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc5OT.png)
[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl1JT.png)

Comment: Consider left joining to a calendar table of all needed months then run `LAG` analytic function.

Comment: I am new to SQL so I do not have much knowledge  on it but with some guidance I will be able to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify the RDBMS system you're using, I can't guarantee that this logic will work because every system uses slightly different SQL syntax.

However I used [Rasgo](https://docs.rasgoml.com/rasgo-docs/transforms/all-transforms) datespine function to generate this SQL, as it is quite complex to wrap your head around, and tested it on Snowflake.

The main differences between Snowflake and other systems are: `DATEADD` and `TABLE (GENERATOR())`

In case you can't modify this to work in your system, here are the basic steps which you'll want to follow:

1. Select unique accountnumbers
2. Select unique dates (month beginnings?) This is where Snowflake uses `GENERATOR` but other systems might actually have a Calendar table you can select from
3. Cross Join (cartesian join) these to create every possible combination of accountnumber and date
4. Outer Join #3 to your data (might have to truncate your date to month-begin)
5. Filter out rows that dont apply. Like for instance you might have just inserted a row for 1/1/2019 for an account that didn't even begin until 12/12/2020.

```
WITH GLOBAL_SPINE AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) as INTERVAL_ID,
    DATEADD('MONTH', (INTERVAL_ID - 1), '2019-01-01'::timestamp_ntz) as SPINE_START,
    DATEADD('MONTH', INTERVAL_ID, '2022-06-01'::timestamp_ntz) as SPINE_END
  FROM TABLE (GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 42))
), 
GROUPS AS (
  SELECT 
    accountnumber,
    MIN(DESIRED_INTERVAL) AS LOCAL_START, 
    MAX(DESIRED_INTERVAL) AS LOCAL_END
  FROM [7 GL Detail MACL]
  GROUP BY 
    accountnumber 
), 
GROUP_SPINE AS (
  SELECT 
    accountnumber,
    SPINE_START AS GROUP_START, 
    SPINE_END AS GROUP_END
  FROM GROUPS G
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      SPINE_START, SPINE_END
    FROM GLOBAL_SPINE S
    WHERE S.SPINE_START >= G.LOCAL_START
  )
)
SELECT 
  G.accountnumber AS GROUP_BY_accountnumber,
  GROUP_START, 
  GROUP_END,
  T.*
FROM GROUP_SPINE G
LEFT JOIN {{ your_table }} T
  ON DESIRED_INTERVAL >= G.GROUP_START 
  AND DESIRED_INTERVAL < G.GROUP_END 
   AND G.accountnumber = T.accountnumber;
```

You were also doing an aggregation step, but I figure once you get this complicated part down, you can figure out how to finally aggregate it the way you want it.

Comment: Hi, sorry this is for SQL.

Comment: @SamBoo11 "This is for SQL" is like saying "This is for a Car", If your mechanic gives you an answer for the wrong type of car, it probably won't work. Same with SQL, not all SQL is equal and you have to define the *flavor*/RDBMS system you're using.

Comment: Hi Josh, I do apologise as I am a bit new to this. Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)   Nov  6 2020 16:50:01   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)