# How can I add the missing data between 24-02-2023 and 02-03-2023 in my table with the values filled according to the value in SQL?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have a table with the following properties:

```
NUM1 STRING (Examp: 2343)
NUM2 STRING (Examp: 0982)
DOC STRING (Examp: 0987654321)
CLASS STRING (Examp: RED / BLACK - 019 )
COD CLASS STRING (Examp: 9087)
NOME_CLASS STRING (Examp: REDBCK  )
DATE STRING (Examp: 09-10-2022 )
BALANCE STRING (Examp: 10,00 )
```

This table is partitioned by the DATE column. And this table brings the portfolio balances per student, like this:

```
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 24-02-2023, 90,02
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 26-02-2023, 00,02
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 02-03-2023, 80,02
```

I need to perform an output like this:

```
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 24-02-2023, 90,02
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 25-02-2023, 90,02
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 26-02-2023, 00,02
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 27-02-2023, 00,02
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 02-03-2023, 80,02
```

How can I do this in SQL or PySpark?

I've tried chatGPT and other alternatives, but I can't generate the missing dates.

---

Expecting:

```
source table:
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 24-02-2023, 90,02
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 26-02-2023, 00,02
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 02-03-2023, 80,02

destination table
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 24-02-2023, 90,02
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 25-02-2023, 90,02
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 26-02-2023, 00,02
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 27-02-2023, 00,02
2343, 0982, 0987654321, RED / BLACK , 9087, REDBCK, 02-03-2023, 80,02
```

Comment: Complement *

The table has some days of student records, but there are days that do not have movement, the days that do not have in the table, must appear with the balance of the previous day, between the range of start date and end date.

Comment: which dbms are you using ?

Comment: Table in Hive, Hadoop @SelVazi

Comment: @Felipe Isn't the row with the Balance "00,02" should repeat from 26-02-2023 to 01-03-2023 (26-27-28-01)? Why your expected output is only 26-27?

Comment: This is called a date spine. I dont have code that works in HQL to help you but if you google that you should find some articles about it. Basically, unique students cross joined with unique dates, and then take that and OUTER join to your original data.

Comment: @HoangMinhQuangFX15045 yes it should, there was an error when reproducing the example

Comment: @Josh Do you have an example in another language?

Comment: @Felipe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72177347/add-missing-months-with-values-from-previous-month/72177503#72177503

Comment: @Felipe Please check my pyspark answer and check if it works as you want. If it works please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my below Pyspark code. I've explained the code, show the df after each step in the comment

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("date").getOrCreate()

# original data
data = [("2343", "0982", "0987654321", "RED / BLACK - 019", "9087", "REDBCK", "24-02-2023", "90"),
        ("2343", "0982", "0987654321", "RED / BLACK - 019", "9087", "REDBCK", "26-02-2023", "00"),
        ("2343", "0982", "0987654321", "RED / BLACK - 019", "9087", "REDBCK", "02-03-2023", "80")]

# create original DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["NUM1", "NUM2", "DOC", "CLASS", "COD_CLASS", "NOME_CLASS", "DATE", "BALANCE"])

# convert DATE column to a date format
df = df.withColumn('DATE', to_date(df['DATE'], 'dd-MM-yyyy'))

# get the start and end datefor each row using Window Function
# end_date is the Date of next row (lead) minus 1 
df = df.withColumn('start_date', col('DATE'))
df = df.withColumn('end_date',
                   date_sub(lead(col('DATE')).
                            over(Window.partitionBy('NUM1', 'NUM2', 'DOC', 'CLASS', 'COD_CLASS', 'NOME_CLASS').
                                 orderBy('DATE')), 1))
df.show()
   # +----+----+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+----------+----------+
# |NUM1|NUM2|       DOC|            CLASS|COD_CLASS|NOME_CLASS|      DATE|BALANCE|start_date|  end_date|
# +----+----+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+----------+----------+
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-24|     90|2023-02-24|2023-02-25|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-26|     00|2023-02-26|2023-03-01|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-03-02|     80|2023-03-02|      null|
# +----+----+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+----------+----------+

# Replace the last null value in end_date column with start_date
df = df.withColumn('end_date', when(col('end_date').isNull(), col('start_date')).otherwise(col('end_date')))
df.show()
# +----+----+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+----------+----------+
# |NUM1|NUM2|       DOC|            CLASS|COD_CLASS|NOME_CLASS|      DATE|BALANCE|start_date|  end_date|
# +----+----+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+----------+----------+
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-24|     90|2023-02-24|2023-02-25|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-26|     00|2023-02-26|2023-03-01|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-03-02|     80|2023-03-02|2023-03-02|
# +----+----+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+----------+----------+


# the magical "explode" and "sequence" function
# "sequence" to create an array of continuos date, "explode" to explode that array into mutiplier rows
df = df.withColumn('DATE', explode(sequence(col('start_date'), col('end_date'), expr('interval 1 day'))))
df.show()
# +----+----+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+----------+----------+
# |NUM1|NUM2|       DOC|            CLASS|COD_CLASS|NOME_CLASS|      DATE|BALANCE|start_date|  end_date|
# +----+----+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+----------+----------+
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-24|     90|2023-02-24|2023-02-25|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-25|     90|2023-02-24|2023-02-25|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-26|     00|2023-02-26|2023-03-01|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-27|     00|2023-02-26|2023-03-01|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-28|     00|2023-02-26|2023-03-01|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-03-01|     00|2023-02-26|2023-03-01|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-03-02|     80|2023-03-02|2023-03-02|
# +----+----+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+----------+----------+


# drop start and end date columns
df = df.drop('start_date', 'end_date')
# final result as expected
df.show()
# +----+----+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
# |NUM1|NUM2|       DOC|            CLASS|COD_CLASS|NOME_CLASS|      DATE|BALANCE|
# +----+----+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-24|     90|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-25|     90|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-26|     00|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-27|     00|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-02-28|     00|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-03-01|     00|
# |2343|0982|0987654321|RED / BLACK - 019|     9087|    REDBCK|2023-03-02|     80|
# +----+----+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
```